# python - nested try/except question

Tags: python

```
try:
    for i in list:
        try:
            #python code...
        except Exception,e:
            #error handler
except Exception, e:
    #error handler
```

If in the nested try/except it errors out, does the loop continue running?

Comment: -1: asking a question that you could have *tested for yourself* in less time than it took to ask it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does, since you caught the exception. Although if you just have a comment there and not a real line of code, I think Python may complain. (I haven't written Python code in a while.)

Comment: Yes, Python will complain. Use pass in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the typo for "cexcept" in the inner except, the loop should continue. Actually, the parent try/except can not be broken only by that for, but I'm sure this is just a simple example of the actual code.